# Handling Windows NTLM authentication with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, ntlm-authentication

I am trying to run selenium web driver(Firefox) test cases against a web application which uses NTLM authentication protocol.

I used DesiredCapabilities to update the **"network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris"** value with "http://localhost:8080" in order to avoid the display of the authentication window.

The **"network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris"** value is updated but in browser it is still empty.

Questions:

1. How can I set the "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris" value?
2. What is the best way to solve this issue?

Please check the **Screenshot** and the **Code** below for more details.

Thanks in advance.

[image: SSO_Screenshot]

```
public RemoteWebDriver getWebDriverObject(DesiredCapabilities capabilities) {
        String os = SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS ? "windows" : "linux";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "target/test-classes/selenium_standalone_binaries/" + os + "/marionette/64bit/geckodriver.exe");

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

        // check the "Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris value before update"
        System.out.println("Capability before update >>>>>" + capabilities.getCapability("Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris"));

        // update the "Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris value" after update
        capabilities.setCapability("Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "http://localhost:8080");

        // check the "Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris value after update"
        System.out.println("Capability after update >>>>>" + capabilities.getCapability("Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris"));

        options.merge(capabilities);
        options.setHeadless(HEADLESS);

        return new FirefoxDriver(options);
    }
```

Comment: "SSO" is a really broad term and *usually* means OAuth2 now. You are likely to get better replies if you specifically say you're trying to use Windows NTLM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I have to user FirefoxProfile to overwrite all browser config values.

Please check [this](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/977) for more details.

```
public RemoteWebDriver getWebDriverObject(DesiredCapabilities capabilities) {
        String os = SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS ? "windows" : "linux";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "target/test-classes/selenium_standalone_binaries/" + os + "/marionette/64bit/geckodriver.exe");

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.merge(capabilities);
        options.setHeadless(HEADLESS);

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "http://localhost:8080");
        profile.setPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", false);

        options.setProfile(profile);
        options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.DEBUG);
        return new FirefoxDriver(options);
    }
```